# Add new set of variables using for loop with left join in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm trying to workout a for loop in R. But something went wrong and the loop  is overwriting the data

This is the input

```
> dput(data)
structure(list(ym = c(201809L, 201809L), hd_001 = c("YA01", "YA01"
), KeyIdOrg = c("16940.200812.0.10.20100831", "4000.201203.1.10.20150313"
), prevKeyIdOrg = c("16940.200812.0.10.20100831", "4000.201103.1.10.20150313"
), prevKeyIdOrg2 = c("16940.200612.0.10.20100831", "4000.201203.1.10.20150313"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

```
pykey = "prevKeyIdOrg"
key = "KeyIdOrg"
colNames = c("ym", "hd_001", "prevKeyIdOrg", "KeyIdOrg", "prevKeyIdOrg2")
```

This is the script I've written

```
  
  pykey = c("prevKeyIdOrg", "prevKeyIdOrg2")
  for (i in 1:length(pykey)){
    pyData = data[!is.na(data[, key]), c(key, colNames)] %>% 
    distinct(.)
 
    j = pykey[i]
    names(pyData) = paste0(strrep("p", i), names(pyData))
    names(pyData)[names(pyData) == paste0(strrep("p", i), key)] = j
    print(names(pyData))
    
    pyData = pyData[!is.na(pyData[, j]), ] %>% 
      distinct(.)
    
    result = data %>% 
      left_join(., pyData, by = j) %>% 
      distinct(.)
  }
```

In the result, the data gets overwritten and I'm not knowing where to address that part.

```
> result
      ym hd_001                   KeyIdOrg               prevKeyIdOrg              prevKeyIdOrg2    pym phd_001              pprevKeyIdOrg
1 201809   YA01 16940.200812.0.10.20100831 16940.200812.0.10.20100831 16940.200612.0.10.20100831 201809    YA01 16940.200812.0.10.20100831
2 201809   YA01  4000.201203.1.10.20150313  4000.201103.1.10.20150313  4000.201203.1.10.20150313     NA    <NA>                       <NA>
3 201809   YA01 16940.200812.0.10.20100831 16940.200812.0.10.20100831 16940.200612.0.10.20100831     NA    <NA>                       <NA>
4 201809   YA01  4000.201203.1.10.20150313  4000.201103.1.10.20150313  4000.201203.1.10.20150313     NA    <NA>                       <NA>
                 pKeyIdOrg.1             pprevKeyIdOrg2   ppym pphd_001            ppprevKeyIdOrg              ppKeyIdOrg.1
1 16940.200812.0.10.20100831 16940.200612.0.10.20100831     NA     <NA>                      <NA>                      <NA>
2                       <NA>                       <NA>     NA     <NA>                      <NA>                      <NA>
3                       <NA>                       <NA>     NA     <NA>                      <NA>                      <NA>
4                       <NA>                       <NA> 201809     YA01 4000.201103.1.10.20150313 4000.201203.1.10.20150313
            ppprevKeyIdOrg2
1                      <NA>
2                      <NA>
3                      <NA>
4 4000.201203.1.10.20150313
```

Can anyone assist me with this? I want the result to be appended and not to be overwritten

Comment: I would like to help but honestly admit that I do not understand what you are striving for. Can you describe in simple words what result you want to achieve?

Comment: I have rephrased my question and I hope it is easier to understand now.

Comment: Please share what you want the expected output to look like in your question description.

Comment: Yes! I've added in my question description.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is still very confusing. I tried to analyze your code but I can't understand what you expect. I understand that this is an attempt to copy values from one variable to another new one. But it's very unclear what variables you want in the data frame after all this operation. Can you write it straight, e.g. like this I now have the following variables `ym, hd_001, KeyIdOrg ...`. After starting the program, I expect to have the following variables `ym, hd_001, KeyIdOrg, pKeyIdOrg1, pKeyIdOrg2 ...` which will hold the values from the variables ....